# How does one install a texture pack on ipad

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I know how to download a vanilla resource pack for Minecraft from https://aka.ms/resourcepacktemplate

I would like to edit it myself, I know how to do that. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to install it on my iPad.

Is this possible without going through some random website or installing third-party apps. I feel I could just edit the files, zip them, and then use [missing steps] to upload the pack to my iPad.

What are the missing steps ?

Comment: That's the thing. I can edit the files just fine. I already did. I just want to put the edited .zip on the tablet.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload files into your game storage directly via iTunes. Simple go to:

```
[Your device here] > Apps > Minecraft
```

and if you scroll down, there is an option to upload/download shared app files. You should see a bunch of folders (I don't have an iPhone, but this is recalling from when I had one) and there should be a behaviour packs folder.

Comment: Awesome, will try this and let you know